# Unbounded sequences with divergent subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

$\{X_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence of real numbers. 
I'm looking for a subsequence of $\{X_n\}$ that diverges to either $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$.

Since $\{X_n\}$ is unbounded then it is either not bounded from above, not bounded from below, or not bounded from above nor below.

Taking the case where $\{X_n\}$ is not bounded from above, 
it is possible to find $m$ such that $X_m > M$ where $M$ is a positive real number. 
How can we find a subsequence that diverges to $+ \infty$?

Comment: Since $(x_n)$ is not bounded from above, for each $n\in\mathbb N$ there is some $k(n)\in\mathbb N$ such that $k(n)>k(n-1)$ and $x_{k(n)}\geq n$. Now, consider the subsequence $(x_{k(n)})_n$...

Comment: That, or $$x_{k_{n+1}}\geqslant x_{k_n}+1$$